# Installing GDAL on MacOS with Homebrew?

Tags: gdal, installation, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, mac

I am trying to install GDAL on MacOS with `Homebrew`. But failed. I started with the following commands:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install gdal --HEAD
brew install gdal —-only-dependencies
brew install gdal
pip3 install gdal
```

The first command check if I have installed the `Homebrew`. The others are step by step installation of `gdal`. It works fun when I try to take a look with the version of `gdal`:

```
gdal-config --version
# out put: 3.0.2
```

But when I trying to convert .tif to .raw with `gdal_translate`:

```
gdal_translate –ot UInt16 –scale –of ENVI –outsize 1025 1025 srtm_59_05.tif heightmap.raw
```

There comes the following problem.

```
dyld[54967]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.91.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/[my_username_here]/opt/anaconda3/lib/libgdal.26.dylib
Reason: tried: '/Users/[my_username_here]/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), 
'/Users/[my_username_here]/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), 
'/Users/[my_username_here]/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/local/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file)
[1]    54967 abort      gdal_translate –ot UInt16 –scale –of ENVI –outsize 1025 1025
```

What should I do?

---

The problem seems comes from something called `poppler`, so I ran

```
brew reinstall poppler
```

It gives me

```
Warning: poppler 21.12.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 21.12.0, run:
brew reinstall poppler
```

If I reinstall `poppler`, the error is still there.

---

Here is the result of searching the folder of `poppler`, using

```
# locate the folder of poppler, gives "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0"
brew ls --verbose poppler
# search for keyword "poppler" in filenames
find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0 -name '*poppler*'
```

It gives

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/.brew/poppler.rb
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/poppler_private_export.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/poppler-config.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-annot.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-page.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-attachment.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-features.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-enums.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-form-field.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-date.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-action.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-layer.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-movie.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-document.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-macros.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-structure-element.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/glib/poppler-media.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-form.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-export.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-optcontent.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-page-transition.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-annotation.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-qt6.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-link.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-version.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/qt6/poppler-media.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-page.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-image.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-global.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-font-private.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-page-transition.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-toc.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-rectangle.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-page-renderer.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-destination.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler_cpp_export.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-version.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-embedded-file.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-font.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-qt6.3.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/pkgconfig/poppler.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-cpp.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-glib.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-qt6.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-qt6.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-cpp.0.9.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-glib.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-cpp.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-glib.8.22.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-qt6.3.1.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-cpp.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-glib.8.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler.116.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-cpp.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler.116.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/lib/libpoppler-glib.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/share/pkgconfig/poppler-data.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/21.12.0/share/poppler
```

Not even I file is in format `libpoppler.[A NUMBER].dylib`.

Comment: There is `libpoppler.116.dylib`, but no `libpoppler.91.dylib`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved:

As https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/5348 issue.

> It looks to be a mix of Conda and homebrew in your system. Perhaps try deactivating your Conda environment. I'm afraid I can't help more.

Just shot down Anaconda and redo everything with only Homebrew.

Comment: Not for me, I don't have conda, but I sure as heck get this error.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Can you post a question and your output? Then people can work out the problem.

Comment: Not in a comment, and the actual 4 hours brew log full of errors is not something I'm going to try to reduce into something easy to post unfortunately. It's a complete horror show.